# how to retrieve firebase database values to calculate average

Tags: swift, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

I've been trying to create a social app that allows people to give ratings of others. I have been able to retrieve and display the ratings for each comment, but I've been having difficulty obtaining all the ratings to calculate an average.

Here is my code:

```
 func observeStars() {

    guard let toId = users?.id else {
        return }
    let placesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Review")

    placesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children {

            let placeSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let ratingsSnap = placeSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "STAR")
            print(ratingsSnap)
            let count = ratingsSnap.childrenCount
            var total: Double = 0.0
            for child in ratingsSnap.children {
                print(child)
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let val = snap.value as! Double
                total += val
            }
            let average = total/Double(count)
            print(average)

        }
    })
}
```

My firebase database structure is shown here:

```
{  
"Review" : {  

"75YFHCGX8WQyP3qlyvQKNohgCvQ2" : {  
  "-LM9OW1eLcS9yr3JZxP5" : {  
    "FROM" : "AV4RFwIlSNdnryfPPCl6SfLOzBZ2",  
    "STAR" : 3,  

    "TIMESTAMP" : 1.5366990112576609E9,  
    "TO" : "75YFHCGX8WQyP3qlyvQKNohgCvQ2"  
  },  

  "-LM9OoyD8A8HWZ387Ln9" : {  
    "FROM" : "MAc9ouJnAacHddqDMRet3K9SkZq1",  
    "STAR" : 2,  

    "TIMESTAMP" : 1.5366990928939629E9,  
    "TO" : "75YFHCGX8WQyP3qlyvQKNohgCvQ2"  
  }  
},  

"MAc9ouJnAacHddqDMRet3K9SkZq1" : {  
  "-LM9Oa1zGbRjdCERwoDX" : {  
    "FROM" : "AV4RFwIlSNdnryfPPCl6SfLOzBZ2",  
    "STAR" : 4,  

    "TIMESTAMP" : 1.536699031758939E9,  
    "TO" : "MAc9ouJnAacHddqDMRet3K9SkZq1"  
  }  
}
```

I would like to use the child node "STAR" for my calculations

Please, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please do not include images and links in questions. Include code and structures as text. To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy an paste a snippet of your structure. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the issue; the structure is probably too deep and your code doesn't match the structure.

You're observing the Review node which has two child nodes

```
Review
   -75YFH...
   -MAc9ou...
```

and keep in mind those those child nodes also have child nodes.

```
-7590W...
   -LM90W...
   -LM90o...
-MAc9ou...
   -LM90a
```

The for loop is looping over the top level child nodes of -75YFH and -MAc9ou So this code

```
let placeSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
let ratingsSnap = placeSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "STAR")
```

is really

```
let ratingsSnap = -75YFH.childSnapshot(forPath: "STAR")
```

and

```
let ratingsSnap = -MAc9ou.childSnapshot(forPath: "STAR")
```

and as you can see STAR is not a child of those nodes.

Based on your structure another loop is needed inside each of the two top nodes of -75YFH and -MAc9ou to iterate over their children and retrieve the STAR node

```
   var counter = 0      
   placesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children { //this is -75YFH and -MAc9ou
            let placeSnap = child as! DataSnapshot 
            for childOfPlace in placeSnap.children { //this is -LM90W and -LM90o
                 let childOfPlaceSnap = childOfPlace as! DataSnapshot                     
                 //let ratingsSnap = childOfPlaceSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "STAR")
                 //I prefer the following...
                 let dict = childOfPlaceSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                 let val = dict["STAR"] as! Int
                 counter += val
            }
        }
        print("total stars: \(counter)") //or tableView.reloadData()
    })
```

Note: typed that code on my iPad so it's untested so don't copy paste. The concept is sound.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jay. I'm able to obtain the different STAR values using your suggested code. But then when I try to add the values under each child nodes, it only shows the individual values instead of the sum of the values. I used the following code:                                    
    let dict = childOfPlaceSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                    let val = dict["STAR"] as! Int
             
                var total: Int = 0
                total += val
                let average = total/Int(count)

Comment: @estelyk I was leaving calculating the sum up to you. But I have added it into the count with a simple counter.

Comment: So, I tried the code again, but I noticed it runs through the nodes -7590W... and -MAc9ou... from top to bottom 3 times when I load the data in my console. Another problem is that when I try to get the total of STARS, instead of getting '5' from -7590W and just a '4' from -MAc9, the console shows 3,5,9. Again the values repeat 3 times. The average ends up being '1.5', '2.5', '9' instead of just 2.5 and 4. Thanks again for any advice!

Comment: Nevermind, I think I figured it out. I forgot I was using the function in tableViewCell. Maybe this is why the data is being read multiple times?

Comment: @estelyk The data will **not** be read multiple times when using .observeSingleEvent. The entire node will be read once and no observer will be left, so no other events will be generated. The problem is that, if you put the function in a tableView cell, every time the cell is created/updated, the function will be called. That's the wrong design pattern; it should be called say, in viewDidLoad to populate your dataSource, then tableView.reloadData() would be called to then display the loaded data in the tableView. The tableView.reloadData() would be right where the *print* statement is.